# Difficulty with Intersection Theory on a Manifold with Boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, intersection-theory

I'm having trouble understanding a certain situation having to do with (topological) intersection numbers of submanifolds of a manifold *with boundary.* This whole question will be based on theorem 11.9 in chapter 6 of "Topology and Geometry" by Bredon. This is solely due to the fact that I haven't been able to find any other reference that develops topological intersection theory on a manifold with boundary (suggestions for such references are most welcome).

Anyway, the theorem (also quoted more fully in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226699/question-on-bredons-theorem-11-9-about-the-duality-of-intersection-product-and)) states that given a smooth manifold with boundary $W$, and $N, K $ two smooth manifolds with boundary embedded in $W$, such that $N$ meets $K$ transversely in $W - \partial W$, and $N$ meets $\partial W$ transversely in $\partial N$, and $K$ meets $\partial W$ transversely in $\partial K$, then it follows that $[K\cap N]_W = [N]_W \bullet [K]_W$, where $[M]$ means the homology class of $M$ in $H_i(W, \partial W)$, and $\bullet$ is the intersection product.

In words, the intersection product of the homology classes of $N, K$, in the **reduced** homology group mentioned above, is the homology class of their set-theoretic intersection.

Now consider the following situation: let $W$ be the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. This is a manifold with boundary; to make it smooth, round the corners slightly (this is irrelevant for the example). Also let (where $[(a,b),(c,d)]$ means the straight line segment from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$)

$N = [(0.2, 0),(0.2, 1)]$

$N' = [(0.2, 0),(0.2, 0.5)] \cup [(0.2, 0.5),(0.8, 0.5)] \cup [(0.8, 0.5),(0.8, 1)]$

$K = [(0.5, 0),(0.5, 1)]$

Again, technically $N'$ is not smoothly embedded in $W$, but round its corners slightly to make it smooth (this is irrelevant to the example anyway).

Now clearly $N, K$ satisfy the transversality conditions of the theorem. Their set-theoretic intersection is empty. And $N', K$ also satisfy the transversality conditions; but their set-theoretic intersection is nonempty, and consists of the point $(0.5, 0.5)$. The problem with this is that $N, N'$ are clearly homologous to each other as cycles in $H_i(W, \partial W)$, because their difference is homologous to 0 in that group (their difference is the three sides of a rectangle whose fourth side is in $\partial W$. In particular that rectangle is homotopic to a point). This means that according to the theorem above, $[K\cap N]_W$ and $[K\cap N']_W$ should agree, because they are both equal to $[N]_W \bullet [K]_W = [N']_W \bullet [K]_W$ (this equality follows because $N$ and $N'$ are homologous). But they seem to not agree, since one of them is the homology class of the empty cycle and the other is the homology class of a single point. What am I missing?

Comment: my initial reaction is that all of your lines and points can be moved onto $\partial W$ and thus they are all zero in relative homology.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus You are right, and this seems to solve the discrepancy described in the question. However, doesn't this imply that the intersection form of any manifold with boundary is always trivial (the zero form)? Since any finite set of points can always be moved to the boundary, thus is zero in relative homology. But according to some other questions here (like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4287573/intersection-form-of-a-4-manifold-with-boundary?rq=1 ), the intersection form on a manifold with boundary is a concept that makes sense and is not necessarily trivial.

Comment: In so far as $H_0(W,\partial W)=0$ I think you are right. I dont have a good nontrivial example in mind, but I think you can construct one by taking $X$ to be a manifold without boundary and non trivial intersection theory, then take $X\times I$ with the obvious boundary, then the dimensions will be increased by one, you should have the same intersections though.

Comment: The intersection form (in dim 4, say) pairs $H_2(W)\times H_2(W)\cong H^2(W,\partial W)\times H^2(W,\partial W)\rightarrow H^4(W,\partial W)\cong H_0(W)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, whereas you seem to be pairing $H_2(W,\partial W)\times H_2(W,\partial W)\cong H^2(W)\times H^2(W)\rightarrow H^4(W)\cong H_0(W,\partial W)=0$.